# Error: Process aborted, when installing zip in Moto Razr XT910

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I rooted my Motorola Razr XT910 already, then I followed the process and everything went excellent. But when I wiped my data, cache, and the dalvik cache, and then choosing install zip, I received the message that the process aborted!

I realized that I didn't backup and reset. So my ROM (the last one) was gone! I thought to transfer other files for the ROM I wanted to install, but everything said that it aborted! All of them.

Every time I plugged my phone LED color was white. I thought it means that there is no battery, and the computer isn't strong enough to charge the phone.

- I plugged it into the wall and it turned on showing Motorola's logo (happens every time you turn it on) and remains stuck on that logo.
- I plugged it out and the logo was gone.
- I plugged back in and the logo showed up again, so I thought it's just the battery. After 12 hours and more the logo was still there.
- I plugged out the phone from charging, and the logo stayed there.
- I plugged it into the computer and the white LED light lit up.

How do I resolve this highly problematic issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the correct ROM. It seems like your .zip file is not adequate.

To transfer it to the phone, enter recovery, and then tranfer either by`adb push` command, or by entering "ADB sideload" option (in recovery), and then using `adb sideload` command on PC.